# Shell: Run other command with all but one parameter

Tags: git, bash, shell

I want to create a script name `git-as` which is basically an alias for calling `git` with a bunch of pre-defined parameters.

```
git --git-dir="$1/.git" --work-tree="$1/" <<OTHER PARAMS>>
```

When I want to call git in another repository, I use:

```
git-as "$SRC_REPO" commit -m "Changes made to $CLASS_NAME"
```

How do I get the "other params" bit working properly?

Keep in mind, I **don't** want the `$1` param (containing the repository location) to be passed to git. Also, the other parameters may include double quotes such as the example shows them used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash (but not all other shells), you can use a variant on [array slicing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005#Retrieving_with_modifications) to pick out some of the arguments without having `shift` the others first:

```
#!/bin/bash
git --git-dir="$1/.git" --work-tree="$1/" "${@:2}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Shell scripts allow the use of `shift n` to left shift the $*/$@ args which may suit your purpose.

```
# t.sh
echo ARGS $*
shift 
echo ARGS $*
```

`bash t.sh 1 2 3 4 5` gives

```
ARGS 1 2 3 4 5
ARGS 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: `$*` will run into trouble if any arguments have spaces or other funny characters (e.g. a multi-word commit message). Use `"$@"` instead (and don't leave off the double-quotes!)

Comment: Agreed - after all these years $* is my default response. :/

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
readonly Directory="$1"
shift
git --git-dir="$Directory/.git" "$@"
```

First, this copies the repository location (`$1`) to another variable (`$Directory`).  Then it uses [`shift`](http://ss64.com/bash/shift.html) to move all the program arguments to the left by one, so `$@` just contains the arguments that were intended for Git.  From there, it's just a simple matter of calling Git with the new arguments.